# Using @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() + Insert, together in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The code is like this

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE (VAL1,VAL2,VAL3) VALUES (X,Y,Z)

   GetLastInsertID @tablename='TABLE'
```

GetLastInsertID is this Stored Procedure:

```
   SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID FROM TABLE
```

How do I get the stored procedure to return the 'LastID' as requested in the Select @@IDENTITY statement above?

I get the following error:

```
   Incorrect syntax near 'GetLastInsertId'.
```

...but this works fine when executed by itself:

```
   GetLastInsertID @tablename='TABLE'
```

Okay, thanks i updated it to Scope_Identity().  But you're saying not to put it in a different SP, to put it in the same SP as the Insert?

Again, i still am getting an error when i combine an insert with this:

```
   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastID FROM TABLE
```

Here is the new error message:

```
   There is already an object named 'TABLE' in the database.
```

Comment: Using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is preferable instead of `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: @Joe: see [Joel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236141/using-identity-insert-together-in-stored-procedures/7236192#7236192), SCOPE_IDENTITY wouldn't work because a stored-procedure is a different scope.

Comment: See [Identity Crisis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224821(SQL.80).aspx) for why @@IDentity is bad. Its an old article but the title is easy to remember

Comment: @Tim - The OP should drop the idea of using a stored proc for this. It needs to be called in the same context. `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is actually less to type than `EXEC GetLastInsertID @tablename='TABLE'` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad idea to separate this into a stored procedure at all, because a stored procedure creates a new scope/context. That leaves you open to grabbing the wrong ID number. If one user in a session inserts many rows together, you might get the wrong result.

Instead, you almost always want the scope_identity() function, and you want to call it in the same context as the statement that created the new record.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "If one user in a session inserts many rows together, you might get the wrong result.". AFAIK the only issue is triggers (and a bug with parallelism that applies to both `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`)

Comment: @Martin - see this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) - `SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.`  So @@identity can have trouble anytime you have multiple inserts in the same session, even if the scope is different. Triggers are just the most common example.

Comment: @Martin - sure. Stored procedures (ie: this very question) ;)

Comment: Yes. I would always check the value immediately after the `INSERT` so wasn't really thinking about that kind of case! Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

In the first place you do not ever want to use @@identity as it can break if someone adds a trigger.

What you want to use is the OUTPUT clause or scope_identity.  See Books online for examples of how to use OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

your error is in your failure to include the `EXECUTE` command, try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (VAL1,VAL2,VAL3) VALUES (X,Y,Z)

EXEC GetLastInsertID @tablename='TABLE'
```

the `EXEC` is assumed when you attempt to run a procedure with no other commands, however when you include the `INSERT` it makes the `EXEC` required.

Now, you really need to determine if what you are trying to do is a good design.

try this:

```
DECLARE @LastId int
INSERT INTO TABLE (VAL1,VAL2,VAL3) VALUES (X,Y,Z)
SELECT @LastID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my sample code that does this.  (But the stored proc doesn't add any value.)

```
--First create a test table.
    create table test
    (id int identity,
    name varchar(30))
    go

--A stored proc that returns the scope_identity()  
    create proc dbo.spTest
    as

    insert into test(name)
    values ('test')

    return scope_identity()

    go


-- Sample call
    declare @newId int

    exec @newId = spTest

    print @newId
```

Comment: The SP looks just like that, but it still gives an error when the SP is being saved/altered:

Msg 2714, There is already an object named 'spTest' in the database.

Comment: Mixing `return` in is a very bad idea, stored procedures should never use `return` (it was ok to use it for error codes pre SQL 2005, but now you can use RAISERROR and throw instead). Use an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: if you already have a sp named spTest you would change the "create proc" to "alter proc".

Comment: @Remus this is obviously a simplified example.

Comment: @Remus " stored procedures should never use return"  where does it say that?

Comment: I say that. Experience will show that most tools cope with difficulty in handling return values from stored procedures. But even more obvious is the issue of type, as stored procedures have a fixed type (int) while output values can have any type. Case in point, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `NUMERIC(38,0)` not `int`.